# Having labels instead of number on axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I'm quite new so sorry if I do things wrong but im trying to have labels (North,South.. etc) instead of number but I cannot do it correctly. If you have any Idea ? Here is part of the code :

```
x_label_list = ['North', 'South', 'East', 'West', 'South-Est-Est','South-Est-South','South-West-West', 'South-West-South', 'North-West-West', 
          'North-West-Noth','North-Est-North','North-Est-Est']



plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))

plt.imshow(viz, cmap='RdYlGn', aspect='auto')

plt.plot(np.array(snow_lines_by_orient)[:,0], np.array(snow_lines_by_orient)[:,1],label="ligne de snow")
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticklabels(x_label_list , rotation=90)
ax.xticks(range(16),(x_label_list for i in range(16)),rotation=90)

plt.colorbar()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

And it show me this :
[result of my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hougv.png)

As you can see first it dosn't plot the first element of my label list and it dosent put every labels. I have normally an increment of 22.5 (x axes ) over 360 so 360//22.5= 16 labels (for x axes ) so it should fit normally
thanks for your help

Comment: Without knowing how the data looks like, it is difficult to get a good idea of what is going on. It would really help if you added the dimensions of `viz` (`print(viz.shape)` ?) and the contents of `snow_lines_by_orient`. Normally, to set the dimensions of the image, you'd use `plt.imshow(viz, ..., extent=[x0,x1,y0,y1])`. To set the `xticks`, first something like `ax.set_xticks(np.linspace(x0, x1, 16, endpoint=False))` would set 16 equally spaced ticks, and only then `set_xticklabels(x_label_list , rotation=90)` would set the corresponding labels.